# Why is there a difference on Mac And PC Dates on conversion from string?

Tags: javascript

How come when i run this code on a mac and a PC, it returns different values on each. To reproduce run this in the console of chrome on both mac and PC.

```
new Date('2015-01-01T05:00:00.000Z')
```

Its like two different days. Im looking for a way to adjust for this.

Mac Chrome: Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)

PC Chrome: Wed Dec 31 2014 23:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

Comment: I get the same time on both Mac and Windows (Jan 1 0:00).  The only difference for me is the EST on mac vs "Eastern Standard Time" on windows.

Comment: OK interesting i figured out that i had the wrong timezone on the PC VM... Thanks